# Flutter forEach through Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, mobile, native

Hi everyone i got some data i need to foreach through so here is the code

```
extractedData[_username].forEach( 
        (areaName, farmData) {
          print(farmData.toString());
          loadedFarms.add(FarmsDetail(
            areaName, //This is correct i want this value
            farmData, // With this i need to go one more map in
          ));
        },
      );
```

so the areaName is a String and it is correct i need that now the farmData hold more maps inside of it,  so there will be another Map<String, dynamic>

```
{
  area:
  {
    arundel: 
    {
      naam: arundel, 
      access: true, 
      calctime: live
    },
    golden ridge estate: 
    {
      naam: golden ridge estate,
      access: true,
      calctime: live
    }
  }
}
```

there is the json data, so where it says arundel that value changes so i cant just say farmData['arundel'] cause that wont work as that value changes on every single one but that is the value i need any advice?

Comment: Sorry the json code at the bottom should look like this

{area: {arundel: {naam: arundel, access: true, calctime: live}, golden ridge estate: {naam: golden ridge estate, access: true, calctime: live}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to access all keys and values of the map in farmData, right?

You can iterate through all values and keys of a given map just like you already did in your extractedData by using [foreach](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/Map/forEach.html).

You might implement this in the FarmsDetail class or just by

```
farmDetails.forEach((k,v) => print("got key $k with $v"));
```

Comment: my man you are a legend thanks i did not do it exactly like that but you got me doing the right thing thanks so much

extractedData[_username].forEach(
        (areaName, farmData) {
          final farmD = farmData as Map<String, dynamic>;
          farmD.forEach((key, value) {
            loadedFarms.add(FarmsDetail(
              areaName,
              key,
            ));
          });
        },
      );